# Pythonic way to decorate parent method in subclass

Tags: python, python-decorators

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class A:
    def query(self, id):
        ...

class B(A):
    ...
```

And this decorator:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return self
    return wrapper
```

I want to decorate `B.query` to modify its behavior. I've tried the following:

This seems to work.

```
class B(A):
    @my_decorator
    def query(self, id):
        A.query(self, id)
```

I couldn't get this to work:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.query = my_decorator(self.query)(self)
```

What's the most pythonic way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It works, you just had a couple of bugs.

```
class A:
    def query(self, id):
        print(f"A.query {id}")

def my_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f"decorator {args=} {kwargs=}")
        return func(*args, **kwargs) # Call the function in the wrapper
    return wrapper

class B(A):
    @my_decorator
    def query(self, id):
        print(f"B.query {id}")
        super().query(id) # use super() to get the instance of A


a = A()
a.query(1)
b = B()
b.query(2)
```

Comment: This works. But what if I wanted to manually decorate a subclass's function using the my_decorator(func) syntax?